# Value is not getting populated in Number_of_Enrolments__c field

Tags: class, helper

my requirement is whenever a Student Enrolments are created/deleted the Number of Enrolments field on Activity (Parent object) should be updated to reflect the count.

**Helper class;-**

```
public class Eaxample1Trigger {

    Public static void updateStudentEnrolmentonActivity(List<Student_Enrolment__c>lst)
    {
        Set<Id> ids=new Set<Id>();
        List<Activity__c> ls = new List<Activity__C>();
        for(Student_Enrolment__c SE:lst)
        {
            if(SE.Activity__r.Id != null)
            {
                ids.add(SE.Activity__r.Id);
            }
        }
         For(Activity__c ac: [Select id, Number_of_Enrolments__c, (Select id,Particapted_in_activity__c from  Student_Enrolments__r) from Activity__c where id IN: ids])
    {
        Activity__c acti= new Activity__c();
        acti.id=ac.id;
      acti.Number_of_Enrolments__c = ac.Student_Enrolments__r.size();
        ls.add(acti);
    }
        Update ls;}}
```

**Trigger;-**

```
trigger Example1Trigger on Student_Enrolment__c ( after Insert, after update, after Delete) {

   If (trigger.isafter)

   {
       If(trigger.isInsert)

       {
           Eaxample1Trigger.updateStudentEnrolmentonActivity(trigger.new);
       }
       if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isDelete)
       {
           Eaxample1Trigger.updateStudentEnrolmentonActivity(trigger.old);
       } }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Relationship fields are not automatically populated in a trigger context. This means that:

```
if(SE.Activity__r.Id != null)
```

Will always be false. You need to check the lookup field directly:

```
if(SE.Activity__c != null)
```

Note that your code will also fail in some situations if too many records share one parent. You should use an AggregateResult query to avoid this problem. In general, you should always prefer to use `__c` instead of `__r.Id`. There is never a good reason to use `__r.Id` instead of `__c`.

We can also avoid the if statement by removing the null value at the end.

By using AggregateResult, though, we also need to pre-populate the activities with a zero value, as if there are no rows, the "last" enrollment being deleted would otherwise leave a non-zero value in the Activity__c record.

```
Map<Id, Activity__c> activities = new Map<Id, Activity__c>();
for(Student_Enrolment__c record: lst) {
  activities.put(record.Activity__c, new Activity__c(Id=record.Activity__c, Number_of_Enrolments__c=0.0));
}
activities.remove(null);
for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount, Activity__c activityId
  FROM Student_Enrolment__c
  WHERE Activity__c = :activities.keySet()
  GROUP BY Activity__c
]) {
  activities.get((Id)result.get('activityId')).Number_of_Enrolments__c = (Decimal)result.get('recordCount');
}
update activities.values();
```

Finally, note that your trigger should also consider `after undelete` to avoid missing counts when records are retrieved from the Recycle Bin, and for `after update`, if your Activity__c field allows reparenting, you must consider both the records in Trigger.old and Trigger.new.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox